# EWS -- Pop up email to be sent

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, email

I am able to create new emails using Exchange Web Service Managed API in a local desktop application.  These messages contain quotes for products and services.  What I want to do now is open the email before sending it so the user can edit and then send the email themselves.  All users have Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need web-client access, you should be looking at the interop libraries and not EWS. EWS is meant to be run headless without client interaction (and therefore cannot open dialogs in Outlook).

An example of doing so in the interop library would look something like:

```
Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem email = outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
                         as Outlook.MailItem;
email.To = "client@rfq.com";
email.Subject = "Your Quote";
email.Body = "Here is your quote.";
email.Attachments.Add(@"C:\quotes\quote.pdf", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,
                      Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
email.Display(false);
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case but I don't want to open a new instance of Outlook if it is already open.  It there a way that I can use an open instance of Outlook?

Comment: Would have to use `Marshal.GetActiveObject` (more info found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx)

Comment: new Outlook.Application() would work just fine - Outlook is a singleton, so if it is already open, you will connect to the existing instance  If not, it will start it. There is absolutely no reason to use GetActiveObject.