# Interop.Outlook Message in HTML displayed as Plain Text

Tags: html, email, outlook, office-interop

I recently switched from using EWS to using Interop.Outlook ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899527/ews-pop-up-email-to-be-sent)).  The process is extremely easy to use!

Unfortunately, I have one problem that did not exist in EWS: Outlook does not process the HTML body even when BodyFormat is set to true.  In this code sample (VB.NET), the MessageBody does start with  < HTML.  With debug, I verified that BodyFormat was set to HTML when display was executed.  Nevertheless, the email body is displayed as plain text.

```
Dim Outlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem =  DirectCast(Outlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

With mail
    .To = Addr
    .Subject = Subject
    .Body = MessageBody
    .BodyFormat = If(MessageBody.ToLower.StartsWith("<html"),
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain)
    .Display(Modal)
```

The exact same body text, when using EWS displays correctly.

Comment: thats an error prone way to detect html....

Comment: What would you suggest?  The BodyFormat property was set to true even before the if statement was executed.  Either way, it still displays the HTML as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  .Body = MessageBody
```

The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class is a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item (without formatting). You need to set the body format first (if required). By default Outlook uses the HTML format.

```
With mail
.To = Addr
.Subject = Subject
If(MessageBody.ToLower.StartsWith("<html")) Then
  .BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
  .HTMLBody = MessageBody
Else
  .BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain
  .Body = MessageBody
End If
.Display(Modal)
```

Use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property for setting an HTML markup.

Or just simply:

```
 With mail
.To = Addr
.Subject = Subject
If(MessageBody.ToLower.StartsWith("<html")) Then      
  .HTMLBody = MessageBody
Else
  .Body = MessageBody
End If
.Display(Modal)
```